# download ISP is different to request ISP

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to download an external file using guzzle. This is the code that I use:

```
$url = 'https://testurl.net/dl/test.mp4?mime=true';
$path = storage_path('app/remote-uploads/test.mp4');

$client = new Client();
$client->get($url, ['sink' => $path]);
```

The code works and downloads from localhost just fine but when I push it to production I receive this error:

```
Client error: `GET https://testurl.net/dl/test.mp4?mime=true` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{"status":403,"msg":"download ISP is different to request ISP. request: AS20115 download: AS30083"}
```

I am not quite sure how to go about this and would really appreciate any help!

Comment: When I google your error message, it seems to be related to something called "openload". Does that ring a bell with you?

Comment: The other end clearly has a protection for downloading data that checks where requests come from. I would contact them if you want to get around it.

Comment: Yes, I am using their API to make some download requests. I am just baffled because on my localhost the test works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you are using https://openload.co/api#download-getlink to get a download link and download it then.

In this this I can assume that you hosting provider uses different IP for each outgoing HTTP request, and these IPs are even from different ASs (you think about them as "namespaces", check [AS20115](http://bgp.he.net/AS20115) and [AS30083](http://bgp.he.net/AS30083)). And this particular site (openload.co) treats the situation like a security problem and prevents downloading (the second request).

**There is nothing you can do on the application level.** You have to talk to you ISP about it's routing rules. Maybe ask about (buy) a static IP address.

You can try to play around HTTP 1.1 keep-alive connections to send all requests through the same connection, but it depends on a server, and openload.co might not support this feature.

P.S. Please, include more details in questions in the future. Others are not wizards to read context from your mind :)

Answer (score -1):

if you using vpn. please disable it